# python remove special column from multiple sequence alignment

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, matrix, biopython

I have an [AlignIO](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.AlignIO-module.html) object: 
a,b,c,d,e are ids for each record

```
------------mfelaeySGLL---TLFL-IASFPIFT-SPIG--- a
------------mfelsgyAVLLFFMVIFL-VASFPLLS-SPIG--- b
--------MKLF-------TFLLFFL-LLC-LSMIPLLS-SPVS--- c
------mvATLS-----------FIFGLSVgAAMLSMAS-SLSL--- d
------md------------MFFFLLAFFL-AGMFPVFS-SPIS--- e
```

I want to remove columns which have frequency of '-' above 0.5

```
    SGLL---TLFLIASFPIFTSPIG a
    AVLLFFMVIFLVASFPLLSSPIG b
    TFLLFFL-LLCLSMIPLLSSPVS c
    ----FIFGLSVAAMLSMASSLSL d
    -MFFFLLAFFLAGMFPVFSSPIS e
```

I'm doing it by looping over the columns and if frequency('-')>.5 I use a new variable `al` which is all columns except the current column having '-'>0.5
Below is my code

```
for i in range(len(align[0])-1):
        c=align[:,i]
        if c.count('-')/float(len(align))>0.5:
            print i
            if i ==0:
                al=align[:,1:]
                align=al
            elif i==len(align[0])-1:
                al=align[:,:(len(align[0])-2)]
                align=al
            else:
                al=align[:,:i]+align[:,(i+1):]
                align=al

    print align
```

This is not working because the index is going out of range as the length of align is getting smaller on every cut. How to solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is solved by:

**

- **saving the indices of columns where frequency('-')<0.5**
- **do another loop over needed indices and save these columns into a new variable free of columns where frequency('-')>0.5**

**

Answer (score 1):

Your original code was correct, only the `for` loop was not the right tool. These routines use slicing and do not need extra variables. The first cuts out 1 position at a time, the second cuts out blocks. This might be more efficient if you have many sequences in parallel:

```
def cut_a_gap():
    n = float(len(align[0]))
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        if align[:, i].count('-') / n > 0.5:
            if i == 0:
                align = align[:, 1:]
            elif i+1 == n:
                align = align[:, :i]
            else:
                align = align[:, :i] + align[:, i+1:]
            n -= 1  #  seq. 1 shorter
        else:  #  nothing to delete, proceed
            i += 1
        print align


def cut_gap_in_blocks():
    n = float(len(align[0]))
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        ct = 0
        while i+ct < n and align[:, i+ct].count('-') / n > 0.5:
            ct += 1

        if ct > 0:     #  delete columns [i:i+ct]
            if i == 0:
                align = align[:, ct:]
            elif i+ct == n:
                align = align[:, :i]
            else:
                align = align[:, :i] + align[:, i+ct:]
            n -= ct    #  seq. ct positions shorter
        else:  # nothing to delete, proceed
            i += 1
        print align
```

Comment: This method seems very inefficient, since the alignment is changed iteratively (1 column at a time) versus slicing out all target columns. There must be a better way, but scaling/abstracting slicing of a biopython alignment (i.e., take n slices of varying sizes from the alignemnt) seems to be rather difficult